# How to insert django photologue gallery into a web-page?

Tags: django, django-cms, photologue

I can't understand how to insert a `photologue` gallery into my web-page?
 
I've installed that plugin, added to `INSTALLED_APPS`, updated `urls.py` and added photos to gallery in admin, but have no idea what to write in base.html or in any other template file to start using gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to write your own CMS plugin to integrate `photologue` with the CMS or find something someone else has already written that might meet your needs.

Like [cmsplugin-photologue-pro](https://github.com/raphaa/cmsplugin-photologue-pro) or [cmsplugin-phlog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmsplugin-phlog/0.3.1) but these are quite old so would no doubt need changes to work with the latest version of CMS.